# Unable to load Teams on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-machine

[image]

**I see the following error when Teams starts up:**

When we start Docker Application

Something went wrongCreating "rootNode" subnodes: constructing "BackendServices" in "rootNode": doing migrations: reading actual settings: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value

I have tried uninstalling/re-installing, restarting my computer, etc.

Comment: Try to Delete   YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Docker directory  
(and start or reinstall docker) should work !

Comment: I tried but it is not working

Comment: Identical to me, I started to receive it yesterday, and nothing was changed, had been working several years before yesterday.

Comment: @a_main I tried both deleting Docker , Docker Desktop folders, then reinstalling, nothing works, absolutely same error